# Create a block, that lists all products from one store on a CMS page

Tags: blocks, cms

I just want to add a block into home page, it list all the products from particular store. Forget about functionality, Can anybody help me to create a block that can be included in home page via cms page. like `{{block type="mycategoryproducts/listing"}}`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can use default magento product list block . Or you can create your own module block.

You can use magento default block like below

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Just change `.phtml` file if you want to need design changes for listing of product otherwise magento default `list.phtml` file is ok

Answer (score 4):

I've done something similar a few years ago. I'm not sure if it still works on new Magento versions, but you can give it a try.
Full description and steps can be found here: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2010/01/list-of-all-products-in-website-for.html

The main idea is to create a block that retrieves all the products in one store and use the existing `list.html` to print them.